# Show column data once if rows below are the same

Tags: sql, distinct

I want to show a certain column once if the below rows are the same.  For example:

I have:

```
PO #    Date of PO  Item
4556    2013-06-27  0408240-1006
4838    2013-07-09  0512162-1000
4838    2013-07-09  0808142-1000
4874    2013-07-10  0410142-1001
5034    2013-07-16  0719201-1001
5034    2013-07-16  0716161-1001
5034    2013-07-16  0715141-1001
```

But I would like it to show

```
PO #    Date of PO  Item
4556    2013-06-27  0408240-1006
4838    2013-07-09  0512162-1000
        2013-07-09  0808142-1000
4874    2013-07-10  0410142-1001
5034    2013-07-16  0719201-1001
        2013-07-16  0716161-1001
        2013-07-16  0715141-1001
```

I only want to show the PO once until that field changes.  I don't want to take away any rows.  If the PO# has multiple items, I want to show only the PO# for the first row of the first item.  Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: While it might be possible by using some truly hackish SQL Code, I would advise against it.  Return the data in it's current form and then format it how you would like using whatever programming language is querying database.

Comment: That is a **presentation issue** and as such should be handled in your application (front-end) or reporting tool - this is not SQL Server's job

Comment: Also, what RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: And, how do you know which `Item` is the first?. In your example they have the same date, so how should we decide which comes before the other? (there is no natural order on a table)

Comment: I didn't post code Marc.  All I was asking is if what I wanted to do was possible through SQL because I am basically creating the view I want in SQL and pasting the code in our third party inventory/order software, so my options there are limited as I did not program that software and there is no option in it currently to format it the way I want.  Lamak- there is another field that handles the line number on each PO which I don't have showing.  There is order in the table, it is ordered by PO# ascending.  So basically is what I want possible or not?